# Link NOT working after adding .active class using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

This is on Shopify platform.

I am using JQuery and CSS to highlight an active link in a subcategory list by adding .active class to the element.

After adding the JQuery, the  element is NOT working and doesn't redirect to the link page.

```
    {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
      {%- assign image = block.settings.image -%}{%- assign url = block.settings.url -%}
      <div id="subcategories" class="cat_space_item {{ccol}} brand_item nt_{{block.id}} tc">
          <a href="{{ url }}" class="db" target="{{block.settings.open_link}}">
              <p>{{ block.settings.coll_title }}</p>
          </a>
      </div>
    {%- endfor -%}


<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#subcategories a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#subcategories a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
<style>
  .active { font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; background-color: yellow;}
</style>
```

I tried add the 'on' event delegation but it is still not working.

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#subcategories').on('click', 'a.db', function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#subcategories a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is preventing the link from working.

Comment: Hi,

I removed the `e.preventDefault();` code and the link is now redirecting.
However, the .active class is getting removed when the redirected page is loaded.

How can the .active stick when the page has redirected to the link?

This is my current code.


`
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#subcategories a').click(function(e) {
        $('#subcategories a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the code you provided seems to be that you are preventing the default behavior of the anchor tag () by calling e.preventDefault(); , but you're not actually redirecting the user to the link's URL.

To fix this, you can add a line of code that redirects the user to the clicked link's URL using window.location.href after adding the .active class to the clicked link.

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#subcategories').on('click', 'a.db', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#subcategories a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
  });
});
</script>
```

This will add the .active class to the clicked link, prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag, and then redirect the user to the clicked link's URL.

Comment: Hi Naya,

I added the redirect code and the link is now redirecting.
However, the .active class is getting removed when the redirected page is loaded.

This is my current code.


```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#subcategories a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#subcategories a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To those who want to know my final working code.

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#subcategories a').click(function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeLink', $(this).attr('href'));
        $('#subcategories a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');        
    });
    var activeLink = localStorage.getItem('activeLink');
    if (activeLink) {
        $('#subcategories a[href="' + activeLink + '"]').click();
    }
});
</script>
```